# Restricting plot to shapefile boundaries in r

Tags: r, gps, plot, shapefile

I have analysed a dataset of GPS points using density.ppp to generate a sort of heatmap of intensity of the points, as shown below:

[image]

However, I would like the image to be limited to the borders of the shapefile, similar to below:

[image]

The first image is called as

```
x <- readShapePoly("dk.shp")
xlim<-c(min(912),max(920))
ylim<-c(min(8023),max(8030))
a<-ppp(cases@coords[,1], cases@coords[,2], xlim, ylim, unitname=c("km"))
plot(density.ppp(a, 0.1), col=COLORS)
plot(x, add=T, border="white")
```

where cases@coords are the GPS coordinates of each point of interest, and x is a shapefile which provides the outline for the geographical unit.

The second image is called using this code:

```
plot(x, axes=T, col=COLORS, border="White")
```

Does anyone know how this might be done? Perhaps it's not possible with plot() and I will need another package.

As an aside, the next step I plan to do will be to overlay this image over a map imported from GoogleEarth. I'm not yet sure how to do that either, but will post the answer if and when I work it out

many thanks

Comment: what packages are you using?  maptools and spatstat?

Comment: Well, the first `plot()` uses the `xlim` and `ylim` you provided above. If you want to manually adjust them use `plot(...,ylim=c(0,100),xlim=c(0,100)`

You will find the xlim and ylim values from the shapefile calling `x@bbox`

Comment: If you have the borders of your shapes well defined, you should be able to overplot with `polygon` , defining your polygon between the shape borders and the plot borders, and filling that area with white or other background color.  But I bet some `ggplot` or `maptools` expert will chime in with the correct answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comments - the answer below solved the problem for me, and the packages used are listed at the start of Greg's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `density.ppp` has a matrix (v) that contains the information, if the points outside of the polygon of interst are changed to `NA` before it is plotted then they will not plot.  Here is an example of doing this:

```
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(spatstat)

xx <- readShapePoly(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1],
      IDvar="FIPSNO", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66"))

x <- rnorm(25, -80, 2)
y <- rnorm(25, 35, 1 )

tmp <- density( ppp(x,y, xrange=range(x), yrange=range(y)) )
plot(tmp)
plot(xx, add=TRUE)
points(x,y)

tmp2 <- SpatialPoints( expand.grid( tmp$yrow, tmp$xcol )[,2:1],
    proj4string=CRS(proj4string(xx)) )

tmp3 <- over( tmp2, xx )

tmp$v[ is.na( tmp3[[1]] ) ] <- NA

plot(tmp)
plot(xx, add=TRUE)
```